# How to counter Juggernaut as Technician

Tags: tribes-ascend

I am new to Tribes:Ascend and i kinda like it. My favourite class is Technician.

What bothers me is the fact that most generators are indoors (afaik) and Juggernaut destroy them pretty easily (its their job after all).

How am i as a Technician supposed to win vs him indoors? and even if i win 1v1 the time needed to repair the generator is exactly the time the Juggernaut needs to come back...

So in conclusion my chances to be able do anything as a techician are about 20%.

Am i supposed to wait till some1 is kind enough to come with me? in pubs this does not work.

Furthermore Juggernaut can spam their Fusion Mortar around corners making it impossible to get even near entrances as a regular character.

if we need 2-3 player just to recreate the generator we wont have enough to defend the flag and capture at the same time which is the main goal of the game.

Comment: Do you mean the greenish grenade that shoots the beams? That's the fractile grenade and it's a Brute weapon, not raider. Also, generally it's the infiltrators job to get the Gens, raiders are better at dueling and clearing the flag stand.

Comment: the one that can bounce several times and has a green flare. after 2 seconds it explodes in a huge aoe. i dont mean the disc. I just checked to be sure. i mixed up the classes. it was a juggernaut fusion mortar.. i dont have every class to test. but juggernauts fusion mortar have the same projectile that i experienced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is kinda like asking "I'm paper, how do I beat scissors?".

You switch to rock, of course.

The zeroeth thing you should have done already before this happens is set up some traps in your base - put down some turrets in unexpected corners, lay down some motion sensors, etcetera. They won't do much against a heavy, but they'll usually be enough to keep a light unit out. The flag takes priority of course, but if it's already well defended a quick turret near the generator doesn't hurt.

The first thing you should do, as soon as you notice an enemy swagging into your base, is to issue a quick VDG (voice commands - defend - generator). The worst that can happen is people will ignore it and you'll have to take care of the Eagle infestation yourself, but sometimes you can get a hand which is incredibly useful.

After that, your next step should be to **stop being a technician**. Techs - and especially techs in pajamas, who are loaded out for base defense - are squishy and have blunt teeth. You'll want to switch to a more combat oriented class, preferably one of the close-combat ones. That means (in approximate order of close combatness) Raider, Brute, Soldier, Infiltrator, Juggernaut, Devastator.

If the generators are still up, run to the nearest inventory station and change into your business attire. If they're not, set the switch up anyway - you can use the num pad for this, it's incredibly useful - and go after the jerk who just walked into your generator room; sure you'll probably die, but you'll come back better (faster stronger).

After that, it's just a matter of beating the invader(s) in close combat; you've got the advantage that you can come back a lot faster than they can, and that the rest of your team is going to *really* want the generators back up once they've been down for a while (make sure you you prod them with VDG/VDB every once in a while if they're not getting the hint, but don't spam it).

Once you've defeated the bad dudes who were invading your base, there's usually a station with repair tools somewhere nearby. You can use it to swap out one of your weapons for a standard repair tool to fix your generator. Doing that and then using an inventory station to switch back to technician is usually faster than killing yourself and respawning, since the technician's repair tool is only marginally faster than the standard one.

Comment: thanks for this insightful answer. i will try using the quick-message function and hope it will work. by inventory station you mean ammunition stations? shouldn't i kill myself (with k) and switch to tech after defeating him to repair faster?

Comment: @Wandang There's usually repair tool stations somewhere near the generator room; you can use them to swap your current weapon for a standard repair tool. This may be faster than killing yourself and respawning as a tech, since there isn't the respawn cooldown. You can switch classes at inventory stations (the pads on the ground that refill your ammo when you stand on them, as well as the thing you call down with 4).

Comment: Eagle infestation? How dare you, sand-raker!

Answer (score 2):

My recommendations, way after the fact.  I'd say even with a good jugg, you've got a fighting chance - at least 50-50.

- Thumper is a must. 910 damage per direct hit, usually get 3-400 in there anyway.
- The yellow fractals only shoot out their death rays at a certain elevation.  By jetting to the ceiling and sticking there, you won't get hit for a while.  Not sure about the green fractals.
- Grenades are also huge. 700 damage on a direct hit, which happens fairly often.  Throw them where the guy is going to be (easier said).
- Try to get him in range of a turret, where he won't kill the turret but it's cracking away while he's busy with you.
- Motion sensor spamming will drain his energy, which often is linked to his health, and certainly linked to his escape choices.
- Watch when he fires a green mortar shell and run *toward* him when he fires it.  Thump.  - As always, avoid head-to-head battles.  Watch his firing and retreat patterns and plan accordingly.  Stay behind walls.

Answer (score 1):

Level 1 generators are not worth defending.  Go get some points and upgrade that generator.  The simplest way to earn points early in the match is to go offense and shoot at their defense.

Once you do get the gen level up, you should defend it by placing turrets strategically...

- Where do they keep putting their fractal grenades?  Don't put the turret there.  Where would it be hard to hit with a mortar?  Put the turret there.
- Place two turrets such that while the enemy is aiming for one, the other one is shooting at them from another direction.
- Place your turrets and go back to the inventory station immediately for a spare.  You can place your spare as soon as one of your turrets goes down.

When all else fails - throw a grenade!